# How to import a javascript module in an IIFE (Immediately Invokable Function Expression) function?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a javascript module in an  IIFE (Immediately Invokable Function Expression) function. Unfortunately, I become a syntax error which is the following:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

My `math` javascript module is the following:

```
var math = function () {
  return {
    add: function (num1, num2) {
       return num1 * num2;
    },
    square: function (num) {
       return num * num;
    }
  };
};

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = math;
}
```

I have another javascript file, which looks like this:

```
import "math";

(function() {
    "use strict";
    this.m = new math();
    console.log(m.add(1, 6));
})();
```

The import is defined on the very top, but the syntax error insists, that I have to move the import declaration to the top.

I have also tried to insert the import statement as the very first line of my  IIFE (Immediately Invokable Function Expression) function, but this is not a valid position.

In case anyone knows how this is going to work, please write a comment. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: How exactly is the module with the `import` used? If you're loading it with a `<script>`, the `<script>` needs "type=module".

Comment: Also `this.m` should just be a `var` or `let` declaration; `this` won't be a reference to anything useful in the IIFE.

Comment: @Pointy Since `m` is not assigned a value again, it should be even better to use a `const`.

Comment: @Seblor sure, `const` would be great in this case.

Comment: Also also: "top level" does not necessarily mean that it has to be at the beginning of the file. It just has to be outside of any function or statement block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking JavaScript modules for Python's.`import "math";` will do nothing. First, you need to assign your module's exports in a variable, and you also need to use a relative path, otherwise it will try to resolve it as an NPM module.

Replace

```
import "math";
```

With :

```
import math from "./math";
```

Also, your error `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` may happen if you use an `import` statement somewhere in the middle of a function or method. *All* `import` statements should be at the top level of the module.

Comment: `import "math"` does "do something"; it runs the code of the module and thus all it's side effects will happen. In this case you're right of course, it should be assigned to a symbol. However the error is about how the importing module appears in context, which is probably a `<script>` block without the right `type` attribute.

Comment: The module's execution part is true. However, the error might happen in Node too, if you use `import` in a function for example.

Answer (score -2):

could you please try adding something like below and check again,

```
module.exports.math = () => {
  return {
    add: (num1, num2) => {
       return num1 * num2;
    },
    square: (num) => {
       return num * num;
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: The problem is not with the exporting module.

Comment: If the import is having issues, please try adding "/" or "./" based on the path the math module is located in